# how to upload several images from android by using retrofit and .net core?

Tags: android, .net-core, retrofit, okhttp

I am coding to upload several images from android to server, and one image can uploaded correctly, while several images can not.

I need some help about my code. Server by c# .net core  and android by retrofit+rxjava.

Sever side(C# .net core)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        BaseEntity<string> be = new BaseEntity<string>();

        if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        {
            be.code = "1";
            be.message = "no file";
            be.data = "";
            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(be));
        }

        // change file name with its extension
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() +
            System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);


        var path = Path.Combine(
                      Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/userImgs",
                      fileName);

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        be.code = "0";
        be.message = "success";
        be.data = fileName.ToString();
        return Ok(be);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        BaseEntity<List<string>> be = new BaseEntity<List<string>>();

        if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
        {
            be.code = "1";
            be.message = "files shows no content";
            be.data = null;
            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(be));
        }

        List<string> paths = new List<string>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(
                       Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/userImgs",
                       file.FileName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                paths.Add(file.FileName);
            }
        }
        be.code = "1";
        be.message = "success";
        be.data = paths;
        return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(be));
    }
```

Android side:

Web Apis：

```
@Multipart
@POST("Upload/UploadFile")
Observable<BaseEntity<String>> UploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);

@Multipart
@POST("Upload/UploadFiles")
Observable<BaseEntity<String>> UploadFiles(@Part() List<MultipartBody.Part> files);
```

Calling：

```
ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> files=new ArrayList<>();

            if(list.get(p).localImgURLs.size()!=0)
            {
                for (String url:list.get(p).localImgURLs
                ) {
                    File file = new File(url);

                    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

                    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);

                    files.add(body);
                }
            }



            Api.getInstance().UploadFiles(files)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                            ((ExecCheckActivity)mContext).startWait();
                        }
                    })
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<BaseEntity<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull BaseEntity<String> be) throws Exception {
                            ((ExecCheckActivity)mContext).stopWait();
                            MyApplication.setResultToToast(be.getMessage());
                        }
                    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            ((ExecCheckActivity)mContext).stopWait();
                            ExceptionHelper.handleException(throwable);
                        }
                    });
```

The problem is when i call  Api.getInstance().UploadFile(files.get(0))  it will work, and when i call  Api.getInstance().UploadFiles(files) it wont.

Answer (score 0):

Your service must receive array of files, just modify your back-end code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile[] file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);
```

should changed to:

```
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", file.getName(), requestFile);
```